# Changing Host Names dynamically

Tags: c#, substring

I have files on a local server with the address of `\\localServerAddress\Folder\Program.exe`.  I need to remove the server address dynamically and replace it with a different server address that is being selected elsewhere in the form.  The server names can be different lengths, therefore, I can not use the `string.Substring` function.

So given the input

```
\\localServerAddress\Folder\Program.exe
```

I would like the result

```
\\differentServerAddress\Folder\Program.exe
```

Comment: So how do you know what you *do* want to strip, if it's not always `\test`? Your requirements are pretty unclear.

Comment: it's a server location that i need to change.  we have multiple servers with the same file structure.  I will need to move the files from one server to the other, hence removing the server name and i'll replace it with the new server address

Comment: There are two "\\test" in your example. Which one should go?

Comment: That doesn't actually give us the requirements...

Comment: Maybe look into [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Can you do an IndexOf at the third '\'?

Comment: @KevinFischer perhaps you can show us in code what you have tried thus far as well as try to explain yourself a little bit better in regards to what you are needing.. have you thought about perhaps the `.Contains()` method and `IndexOf` would be good along with some substring and length methods too.. but hard to tell what you are really trying to do here..

Comment: I'll adjust the question.  One moment please

Comment: If there is always a \ before the next name. In the above \FolderName simple delete everything from \\\test to the next \

Comment: if it is always a server why not new Uri(@"\\servername\d$\directory").host; then remove that value

Comment: Question adjusted to make more sense (I hope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always working with UNCs

Then

```
string toRemove = new Uri(yourString).host;
string newString = yourString.Replace(String.format(@"\\{0})",toRemove)
                                    , String.format(@"\\{0})",whateveryouwant));
```

Comment: what does UNC stand for?

Comment: Universal Naming Convention-In Windows operating systems, the UNC name format is:

 \\servername\sharename\path\filename

Comment: Let's say it's not a UNC, because I don't honestly know if it is.

Comment: I'll try it quickly, and see if it works.

Comment: This is very close to what I needed.  I had to tweak it a bit.  This is the ending result
    `string removeName = new Uri(SourcePathString).Host;
    string fullNewSourcePath = SourcePathString.Replace(string.Format(@"\\{0}\", removeName), string.Format(@"{0}", NewSourcePathString));
    NewSourcePathString = fullNewSourcePath;
    return NewSourcePathString;`

Comment: Glad it worked for you just one thing why do  `NewSourcePathString = fullNewSourcePath;` and `return NewSourcePathString;` just `return fullNewSourcePath;` save a step.

Comment: NewSourcePath is used on other forms as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
    string changeServerInPathString(string originalString, string newServer)
    {
        List<string> stringParts = originalString.TrimStart('\\').Split('\\').ToList();
        stringParts.RemoveAt(0);
        stringParts.Insert(0, newServer);
        return string.Join("\\", stringParts.ToArray()).Insert(0, "\\\\");
    }
```

Comment: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: Oops - fixed the error.  Try it now.

Comment: This is good, except it doesn't add the folder name and onward.
Example:  localServer\FolderName\Test.program will be moved to NYCServer\SameFolderName\Test.program.
The only thing that needs to be done is the server name stripped but keeping the rest of the information

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    string path = @"\\localServerAddress\Folder\Program.exe";

    UriBuilder bld = new UriBuilder(path);
    bld.Host = "NewServer";
    Console.WriteLine(bld.Uri.LocalPath);
}
```

Result:  `\\newserver\Folder\Program.exe`

Answer (score -1):

```
    string text =   @"\\test\FolderName\foo.exe";
    text = text.Replace('\\', '-'); \\ this is done as I was not able to make the regex **\\\\\\(.)*?\\** , work.
    Regex rg = new Regex("--.*?-"); \\ if in case the above mentioned regex is made to work correctly please replace the regex with the same.
    text  = rg.Replace(text, "");
    Console.WriteLine(text.Replace('-', '\\'));

    Console.Read();
```